# awk search and combine data from 2 separate CSV files

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed, awk

There is data in two separate CSV files that share a common IP address.

- File 1: `,      4 ,112.175.173.80 ,TCP ,80`
- File 2: `,112.175.173.80, 0, N/A, unknown, unknown`

The end result to look like this:

- File 3: `,      4 ,112.175.173.80 ,TCP ,80, 0, N/A, unknown, unknown`

I used `sed` and `awk` to get the data this far, but have exceeded my knowledge with this challenge.

Comment: The erratic spacing around the IP address is going to make life more difficult than it would be without it.  Can that be fixed by your preprocessing stages?  Also, it is funny to see an empty field being preserved at the start of each line — not impossible, just odd.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the original data you are working with if it is different from this?

Answer (score 1):

If you goal is to merge both files, then `join` is the tool you might be looking for.

```
$ join -t , -1 3 -2 2 "File 1" "File 2"
```

That says: uses ',' as field delimiter.  For the first file, the field to compare is the third one.  For the second file is the second.  The first file is "File 1" and second one is "File 2".

Comment: Note that if there are multiple lines in the files, they must be in sorted order on the join key fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file1
 , 4 ,112.175.173.80 ,TCP ,80
$ 
$ cat file2
 ,112.175.173.80, 0, N/A, unknown, unknown
$ 
$ awk -F' *, *' -v OFS=", " 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3 OFS $4 OFS $5 OFS $6; next} {print $0, a[$3]}' file2 file1
 , 4 ,112.175.173.80 ,TCP ,80, 0, N/A, unknown, unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|(,[^,]*)(.*)|/\1/s#$#\2#|' file2 | sed -f - file1 >file3
```

This turns file2 into a sed script to run against file1 to produce file3.